# Get Value of ASP.NET Control DatePicker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am relatively new to building ASP.NET C# web pages and am just now learning to use controls.

I have a datepicker which is in the form of an ASP Control, and would like to retrieve and use the value in a JavaScript function. Planning to filter a jQuery DataTable based on a date range.

The from and to date HTML input elements are below (in an HTML table):

```
<tr>
  <td>From:</td>
  <td><hei2:HEIDateEdit ID="dateFrom" runat="server" ShowClearButton="true" clientidmode="Static"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>To:</td>
  <td><hei2:HEIDateEdit ID="dateTo" runat="server" ShowClearButton="true" clientidmode="Static"/></td>
</tr>
```

And I am calling the JS function via **onclick** of an HTML button.

Currently, I'm just trying to use JavaScript's `confirm()` function to display the date that was selected. The various approaches I've tried have returned `undefined` and `[Object] [object]`

[Object][object] was displayed when I tried:

```
function testFunction() {
var fromDate = $('#dateFrom');
confirm(fromDate);
};
```

Update:

It seems that I'm just not accessing the ID attribute of the element correctly.

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried in JS?  Sounds like you might be close with the [Object] [Object].

Comment: It's up there; doesn't look to be very helpful though. Would I be correct to reason that the "object" being captured as input is defined along with the ASP User Control?

Comment: The "object" being captured is actually a JQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/ [See the "Returns: JQuery" link for more detail on the page].  You can access the actual HTML DOM element by using the syntax: $('$dateFrom')[0].  Also, do you want the page to post back every time a date is clicked, or do you want to handle this all on the client side with JavaScript?

Comment: Ah that's great, and I plan to set the filters and re-draw the datatable once the date range has been submitted. Open to recommendations though?

Comment: I'm working on something that I'll post as an answer that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows you how to achieve this for a calendar control and you could simply do the same for your user control as well, I've written the code when users select on a date on calnedar control on OnSelectionChanged event, you can use onClick event for your control to do the same as below:

.aspx

> ```
>     <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="cal" ClientIDMode="Static" 
>           OnSelectionChanged="cal_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
> ```

.aspx.cs

> ```
>     protected void cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", 
>                               "confirm('" + cal.SelectedDate + "');", true);
>     }
> ```

alternatively you could have a javascript function on your .aspx file and just call the function from the code behind like this:

.aspx

> ```
>    <script> function onDateClicked(){
>                //do whatever you want here
>                confirm('<%: cal.SelectedDate %>'); 
>                //do whatever you want here
>             } 
>    </script>
>    <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="cal" ClientIDMode="Static" 
>           OnSelectionChanged="cal_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
> ```

.aspx.cs

> ```
>     protected void cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", 
>                               "onDateClicked();", true);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not 100% sure what kind of user interface you're looking for, most of this functionality might be better handled on the client side (unless you have a specific need of the server side).

I have prepared a JSFiddle for you to take a look at here that I believe accomplishes what you want on the client-side alone.
http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/WLt42/

Then in your code:

```
<myControls:CustomDatePicker ID="_CtlDatePicker" runat="server" />
```

Where the CustomDatePicker is your user control that has the javascript functions and HTML for the date picker inside it.

What I did was use a combination of JQuery and the JQuery UI libraries (which provides a 100% client-side date-picker) to populate text-boxes based on the user selection.  If you don't want to use text boxes the datepicker() method can be applied to any type of element on the page you like (what's important is what you do with the onSelect method).

This approach can still be used with .NET controls if you put the JQuery UI date picker javascript code, and your HTML (or ASP.NET controls: textboxes, labels, panels, etc...) in the user control you have created, and then reference those user controls on your page wherever you like.  You could also customize your controls to have properties for what the id's of the jquery date pickers will be.

If you want, I could prepare a VS solution that demonstrates what I mean.

This datepicker has the advantage of being widely supported and not requiring a server-side page post every time you change month, day, or year.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this. xDaevax and Ali Shahrokhi's solutions will work for some situations. In my particular case (OP), I wanted to access the value of the datepicker from an External JS file. In order to do this:

**I had to remove the ClientIDMode = Static attribute.**

Next,

**I used the following syntax to reference the Control's value, using jQuery's getDate method**

```
var from = $("input[id$='dateFrom_DateControl']").datepicker("getDate");
```

And it worked. Thanks again all